# Android search button and search field in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, google-places-api, searchview

Could someone tell me where can I find some example of how to make this (button I presume?) and this search field to be inside the action bar?

[image]
[image: this search box with Google place autocompleteis]

And when you press  a new (activity? Or fragments?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consult the official search example in the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html

Comment: Thank you, it looks like the image I put are using this technique. I know this is not the same question but do you have any idea how they managed to make the search box to look like this  ? (With this kind of padding around it?) because when I try to implement the search view in the action bar it really doesn't look like this

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea of the concrete implementation. Maybe they are playing around with the element styles, but I can't be 100% sure.